# Updatable Page Title Adobe Business Catalyst

Tags: html, templates, business-catalyst

Look [here](http://livingwood.businesscatalyst.com/index).
I want to update the BC page title tag so that it updates and shows the correct page title on every page. Right now it's in the website template and it needs to stay there for ease for customer editing.

Answer (score 0):

`{tag_pagetitle}`   Displays current page title. Must be used within the title tag of the template.

eg.

```
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
    <title>{tag_pagetitle}</title>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
```